# Always Use German - MMM Format in Datefield

Tags: crystal-reports, date-formatting

I'm using the Formula:

```
totext(cdate({DATEFIELD}),'dd.MMM.yyyy')
```

so I get something like `31.Dec.2020`,`01.Mar.2020` and I noticed that the MMM Format is influenced by the Language Setting of the CR Developer.
I would always like to use the German format `31.Dez.2020`,`01.Mär.2020` (Dec <> Dez, Mar <> Mär).

Is there a quick way to hard code the language setting of the month format within the formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple, but admittedly not very flexible solution would be something like the following with hard-coded month-names.

But since the month names will probably not be adjusted for the next 1000 years, that should still be a satisfactory solution. ;-)

```
StringVar shortName;
Select Month(cdate({DATEFIELD}))
    Case 1:
        shortName := "Jan"
    Case 2:
        shortName := "Feb"
    Case 3:
        shortName := "Mär"
    Case 4:
        shortName := "Apr"
    Case 5:
        shortName := "Mai"
    Case 6:
        shortName := "Jun"
    Case 7:
        shortName := "Jul"
    Case 8:
        shortName := "Aug"
    Case 9:
        shortName := "Sep"
    Case 10:
        shortName := "Okt"
    Case 11:
        shortName := "Nov"
    Case 12:
        shortName := "Dez";

Replace(ToText(cdate({DATEFIELD}), "dd.#.yyyy"), "#", shortName)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to tell `totext` to use a certain locale.

You can change the "preferred viewing locale" in CR designer, either by choosing the menu entry or by setting a registry key value (see [this SAP Note](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1969993)), but that's only a user specific setting of the CR designer application (i.e. not effective for other users previewing the same report, or in server side rendering).

I guess you have to roll your own solution to get fixed language month names into the output. You might check if your database (if any) provides a built-in function to achieve this, like SQL Server's `FORMAT`:

```
SELECT FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'd', 'en-gb');
```

If so, you could use a Command as data source or CR SQL expression field to utilize it. If not, just use CR formulas.

One last thing: One can retrieve the current setting of "preferred viewing locale" with `ContentLocale` in formulas. And there's also `SelectionLocale` which gives the preferred locale setting at the time of last refresh. (I don't know if SelectionLocale is stored with the report when "Save data with report" is selected.)